# Problema con para añadir de una librería en codeblocks

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

Únicamente solo me pasa con esta librería y no entiendo el por que y como solucionarlo, he probado de todo , incluso cambiando el patch pero nada, me es imposible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿qué libreria? ¿estas seguro que tienes instalado esa librería?

Comment: ¿como has enlazado la libreria a tu proyecto?

Comment: Esta es https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion , la he construido con cmake y realice un make Install en la misma, luego le he añadido el flag -lcriterion

Comment: ¿Has ejecutado `make install` cuando instalaste criterion?, te recomiendo señalar lo de `criterion` en tu pregunta ¿o piensas que somo adivinos? :-), por otro lado busca donde se encuentra `criterion.so`, para ello puedes usar `mlocate`, mlocate lo puedes instalar con `sudo apt-get install mlocate && sudo updatedb` y despues solo ejecutas: `locate *criterion.so`

Comment: pongo foto arriba de lo que me sale en locate

Comment: genial, podrias buscar tu ejecutable y ejecutar en la terminal: `ldd /ruta/del/ejecutable` y decirnos que obtienes.

Comment: ¿a que te refieres con ejecutable? a ¿libcriterion.so.3?

Comment: No, cuando compilas un proyecto se genera un ejecutable, a eso me refiero

Comment: tengo /Downloads/crik/obj/Debug/main.o: y /Downloads/crik/obj/bin/crik pero usando el comando ldd no muestra nada, pone que el archivo no existen en el directorio. Tambien me pone esto en el compilador Executing: xterm -T crik -e /usr/bin/cb_console_rExecuting: xterm -T crik -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /home/fernando/Downloads/crik/bin/Debug/crik  (in /home/fernando/Downloads/crik/.)

Comment: Ve con el explorador de archivos a la ruta `/Downloads/crik/obj/Debug` y alli debe haber el archivo `main` sin extension yabre una terminal en esa ruta y ejecuta: `ldd main`

Comment: ¿has modificado en codeblocks?

Comment: puse una foto arriba, no entiendo por que no encuentra el archivo cuando yo veo un main.o dentro del fichero

Comment: el icono de software de Ubuntu tapa lo que se deseo ver, remuevelo. ¿esa carpeta esta vacia?

Comment: perdon por la foto,en ella hay un main.o

Comment: me parece que codeblocks esta limpiando esa carpeta, te podria ayudar a traves de teamviewer

Comment: he buscado por stackoverflow que reinstalando la libreria y añadiendole el correspondiente patch antes de instalarla funcionaria, no tengo mucha idea si esto es cierto, llevo con linux dos meses.

Comment: Me es dificultoso ayudarte justamente por tu poco conocimiento, y sinceramente ya me estoy aburriendo, por lo que para mi es más fácil ayudarte via teamviewer y revisar donde esta el problema por mi mismo.

Comment: No te preocupes, he instalado esta librería antes y tenia el mismo error, yo te dejo reputación por la ayuda recibida, Gracias de todos modos